# Zend 2 websockets

Tags: notifications, zend-framework2, phpwebsocket

Could someone bring some examples of how to work with websockets using zend framework 2? I need some hints to start

I would like to achieve some kind of facebooks push messages and real time chat and notifications

If someone could share his exprience with this kind of stuff i would appreciate that so much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook using COMET method for real time chat and notifications. I found screencast about [COMET for PHP](http://www.screenr.com/SNH).